# The size of rt.jar is different between JRE and JDK

Tags: java

What I noticed is that rt.jar's size is different between JRE and JDK.
It is bigger in JDK. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JDK includes among others also the implementation of the [`javax.tools`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html) API which gives programmatic access to the compiler. If you're curious for more, just extract the JAR using some ZIP tool and compare the contents.

Comment: Looks like `javax.tools` is in both JRE and JDK `rt.jar`s

Comment: @Tom: The interface, yes, but not the implementation. I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: the implementation will be in `tools.jar`, I believe.

Comment: Oh you're right, @AndroidNoob: please unaccept this answer so that I can delete it. It's in essence wrong.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, primarily the JDK version contains more debug information.

There appears to be the same number of files in both:

```
C:\Program Files\Java>jdk1.6.0_21\bin\jar.exe tf jdk1.6.0_21\jre\lib\rt.jar | wc -l
17036

C:\Program Files\Java>jdk1.6.0_21\bin\jar.exe tf jre6\lib\rt.jar | wc -l
17036
```

Answer (score -1):

There are more files in the JDK version, compared to the JRE version.